# What should I do when the Lightroom 3 spot removal brush gets stuck?

Tags: software, lightroom-3

Has anyone come across the healing/spot clone brush 'sticking' in Lightroom 3 getting stuck? It happens fairly frequently for me and I've never found a way to solve it, occasionally if I close it and reopen it'll work but sometimes I'll just have to give up for half an hour and then it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

To my 'humble' experience, in LR3 as well as in LR4, the healing/spot brush slows down, and even stuck, when this is applied after sharpening is done. Now, sharpening is the last action I do in LR and things are slowing down far less.
Emptying the cashes and restarting the computer several times while working can help, 
but LR will always be devouring RAM...

Comment: Well this is the thing, it's the only action I was applying (so history was 'imported into lightroom' then spot heal) so the files weren't bogging down like they could have been after a few hours. I'll try killing the cache again though, but it's only a small library (close them off after 3 months). Weird bug!

Answer (score 1):

I've definitely experienced fairly major slow-downs.  I think it's just very processor-intensive.  The problem is that LR doesn't do anything to tell us that it's working and will be back soon.

I just leave the computer until it sorts itself out.  It always does in the end.